# Using ObservableCollection firing Binding.TargetUpdated only on single item

Tags: wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I have three Textblocks with the `Text` Property bound to the items of an `ObservableCollection`:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FadeInTextBlock}" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentAnswers[0], NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FadeInTextBlock}" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentAnswers[1], NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FadeInTextBlock}" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentAnswers[2], NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
```

The Property with `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented:

```
public ObservableCollection<Answer> CurrentAnswers
{
  get { return currentAnswers; }
  set { currentAnswers = value; RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentAnswers"); }
}
```

Each Textblock uses the same style containing a trigger for the `Binding.TargetUpdated` event which fades in the actual text:

```
<Style x:Key="FadeInTextBlockTwo" TargetType="TextBlock">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0" To="0.0"/>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:1" From="0.0" To="1.0" BeginTime="0:0:0"/>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

When I change ONE item in the `ObservableCollection` ALL Textblocks are firing the event and do the fade in:

```
CurrentAnswer[1] = "New Text"; 
// Textblock 1 - 3 do the fade in animation, 
// even if only Textblock 2 has been updated
```

How can I limit the animation to only the Textblock whose bound value has been updated?

Comment: Post the relevant XAML and code (if any)

Answer (score 1):

When you're using indexes you bind to indexer property of your collection and UI does not know which index has changed it is just notified that indexer property has changed without specifying which index so, in your case, it refreshes all 3 `TextBlocks` raising `TargetUpdated` event. What happens is `ObservableCollection` raises `PropertyChanged` event with [`Binding.IndexerName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.data.binding.indexername.aspx) as property name. To solve your problem instead of using 3 `TextBlocks` you can use `ItemsControl`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentAnswers}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FadeInTextBlock}" Text="{Binding NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

this will repeat `TextBlock` as many time as many items you have in `CurrentAnswers`

Comment: But this will not solve the problem with every `TextBlock` refreshing every time, right?
Is there a way to make only the updated `TextBlock` trigger the animation, other than binding to separate properties?
The number of `TextBlock`s is fixed in my case.

Comment: It should solve your problem. I've tested it and it worked and I've also used it elsewhere. This solution does not involve indexer property so it won't get notifications to refresh from it but from `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, which say specifically which items changed, so this will cause only changed item to refresh and trigger animation

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Everything seems to be like I wanted now.